# Unexpected reinitialization of variables declared in VB6 DLL module

Tags: dll, asp-classic, vb6

I have a VB6 DLL embedded in some ASP pages. The DLL hits a Codebase database, an obsure and obsolete database engine (a dialect/variation on [dBase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBase)) that virtually no-one has even heard of. It takes Codebase nearly a second to initialise a new connection, which is unacceptably slow and so I've created a connection pool, managed by a VB class. The single instance of this class is created at the start of a VB module, i.e.:

```
Private m_codebaseManager As New CodebaseManager
```

My problem is that periodically the class initialization method is called again completely wrecking my pooling class and I've no idea why. Terminate does not fire and there's no sign of any crash occurring, so why on earth is initialize called? My understanding is that data in non-class modules persists for the lifetime of the DLL. Is that correct and if not, under what circumstances does a module 'restart'?

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend removing the "New" from the variable declaration. Declaring a variable "As New" causes it to be checked every time it is referenced, and if set to Nothing a new instance of your CodebaseManager will be created.

A better solution would be to declare your variable like this:

```
Private m_codebaseManager As CodebaseManager
```

and then explicitly set it to a new instance when your application starts:

```
Set m_codebaseManager = New CodebaseManager
```

This means you can be sure you won't be creating any unintentional new instances of CodebaseManager. You'll probably then still have a bug but at least it will be an "Object or with block variable not set" error which you should be able to easily fix.

Answer (score 1):

> > My understanding is that data in non-class modules persists for the lifetime of the DLL. Is that correct and if not, under what circumstances does a module 'restart'?

Sort of. Global state (module public/private vars) are apartment specific and is stored in TLS slots. VB6 supports apartment threading only, so each thread gets a "fresh" copy of the global state. Because ASP environment is multi-threaded so each thread gets a separate DB connection "pool".

If you need a real global state you have to use Application object to store it. If you put apartment threaded objects there (like VB6 ones) these can serialize you multi-threaded ASP environment and degrade performance. Use ADO objects or Dictionary objects or anything you are certain is free threaded.

Btw, you can let COM+ do the object/connection pooling for you. If OLEDB provider is a better one it can do connection pooling internally too (SQLOLEDB for MSSQL is an example).

Answer (score 0):

But it's a DLL and not an ActiveX exe, so there's no Main() function and nowhere for the 'Set m_codebaseManager = New CodebaseManager' line to go except in global scope.

Comment: You could create a Register() function in the module and call that from the Class_Initialize of the classes you are exposing in your DLL.

In the Register() function, use something like

    If Not m_codebaseManager Is Nothing Then Set m_codebaseManager = New CodebaseManager

Alternatively, stick a breakpoint on Class_Initialize in your CodebaseManager class and you should see exactly where the additional instances are being created.